# Help! Accidently delete the bin file in the miniconda2. Can't restore from google drive, what should I do?

Tags: delete, undelete

Tried update the Ubuntu system, and downloaded the miniconda3. But the python pipelines didn't work on the new conda environment.

Still got the old miniconda2 file without bin file. What should I do?